# Next.js - npm run build TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, mongoose, next.js

**i am trying to run the command npm run buid it's failing saying failed to generate static pages
**# my error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtOZB.png)

**#
**#
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5oky.png)

**    i am new to next js i am doing it to get the static files in out folder
to try the capacitor but its not building      i think the fetching caused the error if any please tell me what error i have done and how to resolve it**